# Execute SQLite statement with a parameter

Tags: c, string, sqlite, printf

I have this method in C, where I delete a row from a table. I want to pass a parameter which is the primary key and then delete that row.

Here is my method:

```
void eliminarAlumno(char *mat) {
    abrirBD();
    error = sqlite3_exec(conexion, "delete from alumnos WHERE matricula='<mat>'", 0, 0, &msjError);
    comprobarError(error, msjError);
    cerrarBD();
}
```

Where `<mat>` is the parameter. How can I do this?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. You need to first take an array, populate the required string and *print* it into the array using [`sprintf()/snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) and use the array as the argument to `sqlite3_exec()`.

Something like

```
char argument[128] = {0};   //make sure the final array fits in here
sprintf(argument, "delete from alumnos WHERE matricula='%s'", mat);
error = sqlite3_exec(conexion, argument, 0, 0, &msjError);
```

should do the job.

Comment: Sourav, since `mat` is a string and the database field also a string, you must use the single quote to surround the field in the SQL query. I added that to your solution as an edit.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the second parameter of `sqlite3_exec` should be `argument` instead of `mat`.